# How can we download meteor to specific directory and then install it?

Tags: unix, curl, meteor

I have a server where i want to deploy my meteor application. For that i need to install meteor first, but as i do

`curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

I get `.meteor: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device` error. I have checked the disk space using `$dk -kh` command and this is the output:

```
Filesystem                                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol1                                    969M  969M     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                     7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1                                                 190M   85M   96M  47% /boot
abc.net:/my_disk                                          300G  167M  300G   1% /my_disk/test
```

I have 300gb in `abc.net:/my_disk` and i want to use this path for my download and installation. Is there any method i can use to get this working? is it possible to store the downloaded file to other directory except`root`?

Comment: You don't need to install Meteor for deployment. A deployed Meteor application is a pure nodejs application. Meteor is only the develpoment framework offering you thousands of tools and hints out of the box to create nodejs applications.

Comment: so only nodejs need to be installed?

Comment: Yes but with the exact same version as your local Meteor node version. Read more in the deployment article: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

Comment: for deployment i have to do `npm install` right, well i have `node -v`:v0.10.36 and i dont have npm installed. how can i resolve this?

Comment: Install npm and node, you can use `n` to easily manage versions of `node` including which one should be active currently. You can install specific npm versions with `npm install -g npm@1.4.3` for example.

As a side note it's not a good idea to have 100% use on any drive, consider making it larger or moving files around, you can get some pretty unexpected behavior otherwise.

Comment: As i mentioned i have  node -v:v0.10.36 in my server and `npm` is not found as it's not installed. How can i install npm?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple,

in the meteor directory that you have on your development pc run the following commands

`meteor npm install`

`meteor build .. --directory --architecture os.linux.x86_64` Obviously watch for the architecture you are building on.

You will receive a folder called `bundle/` that is one directory behind your current directory.

compress that folder using your favorite tool and move it to your production server. use which ever tools that suit you

Then uncompress the folder in a directory of your liking.  make sure you have npm and pm2 installed (you can google how to do that)

move to this directory `cd ../bundle/programs/server`

install all the npm packages your bundle needs `sudo npm install --production`

go back to the root folder `cd ../../`

make sure there are no running pm2 instances `pm2 delete all`

start the main program `pm2 start bundle/main.js`

you can monitor the logs for the application using `pm2 monit`

PS: if you get a mongoDB error then it's most likely becasue you have not set the destination to your DB `export MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017`

Hope this helps

Comment: All this i know..but npm is not installed in the server and node -v :v0.10.36 my apps node is:8.9.4. how can i install npm and also upgrade node in my production server running rehl 6 server with 64 bits?